# Retrieve Header's Checkbox Object from ListView Windows form

Tags: .net, winforms, object, checkbox, objectlistview

I want to Check/Uncheck the ListView's Header Checkbox When all the Item's Checkbox are either checked or Unchecked.But i am not able to access the object of Header's CheckBox.
I used CheckBoxRenderer Class to create a checkbox.

```
private void ListView_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
        {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            bool value = false;
            try
            {
                if (e.Header.Tag != null)
                    value = !Convert.ToBoolean(e.Header.Tag);
                else
                    value = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            //I want object of this CheckBox that i am drawing.
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics,
               new Point(e.Bounds.Left + 4, e.Bounds.Top + 4),
               value ? System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal :
               System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);

        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }
        }

   private void ListView_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }

    private void ListView_DrawSubItem(object sender, DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawDefault = true;
    }

    private void ListView_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some Code
    }
```

Is there any way to get the Object of Checkbox that i have created using CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox()

Comment: Doesn't the OLV already support checkboxes in column headers by default? Are you sure you need to draw a custom column header? See [this link](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-put-a-checkbox-in-a-column-header)